# модификатор static переменной

Tags: java

Почему если не написать перед int A, модификатор static, то переменная A не читается в методе main. Разве в статичные методы, могут передаваться только статичные переменные?

```
public class Solution
{

public static int A = 5;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A = 15;
}

}
```

Comment: без static - это переменная объекта, а static метод откуда знает какой объект вам надо использовать? У разных объектов эта переменная может же разные значения иметь и какое из них выбрать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод `main`, как вы сами можете видеть, является статическим методом. Он не имеет дело ни с одним экземпляром (объектом) класса `Solution`. Если вы объявите член класса `A` как нестатический член класса, то это означает, что каждый отдельный объект класса имеет свой собственный член класса `A`, А это в свою очередь означает, что  метод `main` должен иметь дело с каким-то конкретным объектом этого класса, чтобы можно было обратиться к его члену данных `A`.

Когда же член данных `A` объявлен  как статический член данных класса, то это означает, что он не присутствует ни в одном из объектов класса `Solution`, а создан вне объектов и может совместно использоваться всеми объектами класса `Solution` в том числе и статическими методами класса, так как в этом случае они не нуждаются в конкретном объекте класса, чтобы обратиться к этому статическому члену класса.